# Read spring yml properties from xml configuration

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I am trying to read properties from application.yml in spring-bean.xml like this:

```
<bean name="#{bean.name}" />
```

Is it possible ? or I should specify location of my application.yml file?

Comment: You are already using Spring Boot which loads those files. Use `${bean.name}` instead of `#{bean.name}`. The latter is a SpEL expression.

Comment: @M.Deinum - Can you please guide here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73784166/how-to-read-application-yml-in-spring-xml-configurations?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes It's Possible

> For YAML Properties

1. You have to use **YamlPropertiesFactoryBean**

   ```
   <bean id="yamlProperties" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.YamlPropertiesFactoryBean">
       <property name="resources" value="classpath:application.yml"/>
   </bean>

   <context:property-placeholder properties-ref="yamlProperties"/>
   ```
2. Then define your property in src/main/resource/application.yaml

   ```
   bean:
      name: foo
   ```
3. Now use can use the property in xml to create a bean

   ```
   <bean name="${bean.name}"
   class="net.asifhossain.springmvcxml.web.FooBar"/>
   ```

Here's my complete XML config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.3.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">
    <bean id="yamlProperties" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.YamlPropertiesFactoryBean">
        <property name="resources" value="classpath:application.yaml"/>
    </bean>

    <context:property-placeholder properties-ref="yamlProperties"/>

    <bean name="${bean.name}" class="net.asifhossain.springmvcxml.web.FooBar"/>
</beans>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I want read values from YAML, not from *.properties.

Comment: How can we read multiple properties from yaml?

Comment: Can you one please guide here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73784166/how-to-read-application-yml-in-spring-xml-configurations?

Comment: How can we read as a Map from Application.properties