# java.naming.provider.url in <bean id="jndiTemplate" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate"> using YAML

Tags: spring, spring-boot

jms.java.naming.provider.url is NOT getting value from application.yaml

```
<bean id="yamlProperties" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.YamlPropertiesFactoryBean">
    <property name="resources" value="classpath:application.yaml"/>
</bean>

<context:property-placeholder properties-ref="yamlProperties"/>

<bean id="jndiTemplate" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate">
    <property name="environment">
        <props>
            <prop key="java.naming.factory.initial">string-works</prop>
            <prop key="java.naming.provider.url">${jms.java.naming.provider.url}</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Read spring yml properties from xml configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46094792/read-spring-yml-properties-from-xml-configuration)

Comment: Please post content of  `application.yaml`